# wordpress fail to call to function add_filter() in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and want to modify the mail 'From' and 'From Name'. So, by searching the internet, I add these code to wp-includes/functions.php (the lines starting with `>>` are what I add, and the line number is same as what it is in `funcions.php`):

```
1  <?php
2  /**
3   * Main WordPress API
4   *
5   * @package WordPress
6   */
7
8  require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/option.php' );
9
10  >> function custom_mail_from($old){
11  >>         return 'stephen' . preg_replace('#^www\.#', '', strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));
12  >> }
13  >>
14  >> function custom_mail_from_name($old){
15  >>         return 'Stephen Zhang';
16  >> }
17  >>
18  >> add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'custom_mail_from');
19  >> add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'custom_mail_from_name');
20
21  /**
22   * Convert given date string into a different format.
...
```

however, I get this error:

```
2014/11/13 15:29:35 [error] 683#0: *7602 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_filter() in /home/www/blog/zsr/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 18"
```

But it seems that it has already `require` the `option.php` file.
So why can this error occurs? And what can I do to solve it?

Thanks~ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it maybe this simple? I am not even sure if I should ask: But do you realy want to load the functions.php right there?

> 2014/11/13 15:29:35 [error] 683#0: *7602 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_filter() in
>   /home/www/blog/zsr/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 18"

The Functions shoud be somewhere here: 
wordpress Main Folder > wp-content > Themes > YourThemeName > functions.php
You're going here:
wordpress Main Folder > wp-includes > functions.php

You should always edit your theme's function, never the core. The Theme's function is enough, to clean up you could include external files.
Afterwards this tutorial should work for you: http://www.artishock.net/wordpress/how-to-change-wordpress-default-email-from-name-and-from-address/

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much~ :)

Comment: @ASenR Please select my answer correct, if it helped you, to close up this question.

Comment: @Fabian...at least write your own comment. No reason to copy and paste mine to the OP.

Comment: omg thank you. WTF isn't this mentioned in every frigging article that just says "modify functions.php"

Answer (score 0):

These functions should be added to your THEME's **functions.php** file, in `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`. There's almost never a good reason to modify core files in `/wp-includes`.

Read more about the [Functions File](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained).

Comment: @ASenR Please select my answer correct, if it helped you, to close up this question.

Answer (score 0):

source file for add_filter is 'plugin.php' not 'option.php'

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Source_File

Comment: Sorry, but I just edited the wrong `functions.php` file... thanks all the same.